# JQuery clearTimeOut not stopping setTimeOut not working

Tags: jquery, settimeout, cleartimeout

I have a simple piece of code which executes on the click of a button, but I need to detect a double click (only one click is required - but I need to alert on two or more clicks).  I have a `setTimeOut` function to pause for a second then move on - but the code I have, which should clear this function isn't working, it's executing the `alert()` but not stopping the `setTimeOut` function!

```
$('.badge').on('click','#badge', function() {
    Click = Click + 1
    ButtonClick()
    if ($.isNumeric($(this).text())) {      
        $(this).css("background-color","#006400");
        BadgeNo = $(this).text()
        if (Click == 1) {
            var timeOut = setTimeout(function(){                
                $(this).css('background-color','#568bc1')
                $('.badge').hide()
                $('.hs').show()
                $('#numberplate').text('')
            }, 1000);
        } else if (Click > 1) {
            clearTimeout(timeOut);  
            alert("Please only select ONE badge number");
            CheckBadge();                   
        }
    }
});
```

Am I making any form of schoolboy error here?  I just can't understand why it doesn't stop the timeout.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `var timeOut` is out of scope when unsetting:

```
var timeOut = false;
$('.badge').on('click','#badge', function() {
    Click = Click + 1
    ButtonClick()
    if ($.isNumeric($(this).text())) {      
        $(this).css("background-color","#006400");
        BadgeNo = $(this).text()
        if (Click == 1) {
            timeOut = setTimeout(function(){                
                $(this).css('background-color','#568bc1')
                $('.badge').hide()
                $('.hs').show()
                $('#numberplate').text('')
            }, 1000);
        } else if (Click > 1) {
            if ( timeOut )
                 clearTimeout(timeOut);  
            alert("Please only select ONE badge number");
            CheckBadge();                   
        }
    }
});
```

slight changes only on the scope of the variable `timeOut` and whether its initialized or not.

Comment: Many thanks @Axel Amthor - would NEVER have figured that out for myself, but it's a good learning curve seeing how different it should be.  Cheers!